# Logic in Flask template rendering

Tags: forms, flask

I am new on Python and flask. I am looking at this code:

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        user = User(form.username.data, form.email.data,
                    form.password.data)
        db_session.add(user)
        flash('Thanks for registering')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

The register.html is rendered ( shown on the browser) at as the last step in register(). Logically it has to be shown on the browser first so that the user can fill in the data. Obviously I am missing something very basic. Could someone help me understand the logic here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let's go over what happens when a user visits `/register`:

1. User types in 'http://address:port/register' and hits `[Enter]`
2. Browser sends a `GET` request to the address.
3. Flask resolves this request to `/register` route.
4. Now, `request.method` is `GET`, so `form` is generated (it's not filled in, though).
   `if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():` block doesn't run, because the method is different.
   So flask renders the template and sends the HTML.
5. Now user sees the form, fills it in, clicks `[Send]` button.
   Browser makes a `POST` request this time, with all fields' values attached to it.
6. Flask routes this request to `/register` endpoint again, because it accepts `POST` requests too.
7. This time `if` block runs, and if the form is valid, user is generated and flask redirects the user.

I hope this clears your confusion.

Comment: The whole thing makes sense now. Thank you abdusco for thorough explanation.